Can't acces Kafka with distant host
I try to access Kafka server (10.10.45.91) from a distant host (10.10.45.90).
VMs Alma Linux 9.x, Kafka Kraft 2.13-3.7.1 on both server and distant host.
Note: thanks to @OneCricketeer I've discover kcat. I've rewrite the question to be more precise.
What I did:
On the server VM (10.10.45.91):
I've add a topic logstash-topic
FW: open 9092 port
Set configuration:
sudo nano /opt/kafka/config/server.properties
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.10.45.91:9092

/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 10.10.45.91:9092 --describe --topic logstash-topic

Works as expected
On the distant host 10.10.45.90:
nc -vz 10.10.45.91 9092 => ok
kcat -L -b 10.10.45.91:9092
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: 10.10.45.91:9092/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1 at localhost:9092 (controller)
 4 topics:
  topic "logstash2" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
  topic "quickstart-events" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
  topic "__consumer_offsets" with 50 partitions:
...
 topic "logstash-topic" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1

kcat -b 10.10.45.91:9092 -t logstash-topic
% Auto-selecting Consumer mode (use -P or -C to override)
%3|1724217508.095|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/1]: localhost:9092/1: Connect Connection refused (after 2ms in state CONNECT)
% ERROR: Local: Broker transport failure: localhost:9092/1: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 fai2ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1724217508.212|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/1]: localhost:9092/1: Connect Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
% ERROR: Local: Broker transport failure: localhost:9092/1: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 fai0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)

It seems that kafka server send back loopback IP (as the main broker) which make kcat to query himself.
Note: When I run a logstash with correct configuration (that work well on server VM), Logstash seems to "query" to localhost, as well.
Seems I got an error on my Kafka config file.
I've try a lot of configuration on field listeners, advertised.listeners and listener.security.protocol.map field.
Maybe something that not work with IP address but with hostname, but I can't find out.
2 days spends on this problem, reading posts and S.O., now I need help :).

Use kcat -L to diagnose listeners, rather than nc

I though that kcat was a specific confluent tools. I'm using vanilla Kafka from Apache source and I'm limited about the linux package I could intall.

It's an open source tool, not specific to Confluent (and most Confluent tools work with Apache kafka)

Thanks a lot, really appreciated. Just dnf it. I rewrite my question with kcat test. Seems it's THE tool for Kafka.

I've modified the wrong properties file, so Kafka can't apply my modifications.
Why:
Kafka (installed with Kraf) got 2 server.properties:
/opt/kafka/config/server.properties
/opt/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties

I've set-up Kafka as a daemon:
/etc/systemd/system/kafka-server.service
ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties

Finally, following documentation, I've set up my Kafka config in  /opt/kafka/config/server.properties which will never be applied.
Thanks to @OneCricketeer, I've check my daemon config and find out.
Adding the conf in the correct properties file make kafka work perfectly.
Thanks for the help and kcat tool.
Hope that could help.

There's no reason for it to be advertising localhost:9092 when using the settings you've shown.

I've try a lot of configuration on field listeners, advertised.listeners

Make sure you are restarting the broker each time. Then look at the startup logs to ensure advertised.listeners contains the external IP.

Kafka... on both server and distant host

Kafka isn't running on that host, it's just a client

something that not work with IP address but with hostname

That would involve your DNS server, rather than any kafka configuration

I restart Kafka with systemctl (I've add a systemd .service). OMG, you just show me the solution.
